# Linux custom authentication with pam_exec

Tags: linux, pam

I'm having trouble finding an example on how to use `pam_exec` to run an external program that will authenticate users when they log in.

I have the following in my `pam.d` file:

```
auth required pam_exec.so debug log=/tmp/aa /path/to/myscript
```

What should my script contain to allow or disallow authentication?

Answer (score 4):

pam_exec will simply examine exit code of your script. If it is not equal to zero you will have denied authorization.

Comment: My script exits with status 0, but PAM still denies auth with `0: NO "authentication failed"`

Answer (score 2):

In reaction to [the above comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15640994/linux-custom-authentication-with-pam-exec#comment89979872_19286219):
In my case, the auth script was OK, but PAM failed at the `account` stage:

```
authentication: pam_unix(postgresql:account): could not identify user (from getpwnam(myuser))
```

This is logged to syslog (if you are tinkering with PAM in docker, pass `-v /dev/log:/dev/log` to `docker run` to see the PAM syslog messages in host's syslog).

The solution was to add the following to the pam.d file:

```
account sufficient pam_permit.so
```